# Woocommerce Bookings resources field resets time selection

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm not a true developer but have to set a wordpress website that can book a football pitch.
I used Woocommerce Bookings and I managed to customize everything nicely.
One thing is a constant pain.

The "resources" field used to book some gear, when used in the form, resets the time and day selected already by the customer.

I think that it's because it's meant to be on top of the calendar and be chosen first to make the available date to display based on the availability of the resources, but it's counter-intuitive for the customer. So i moved it below the calendar.

In my case the resources are available anyway so that's not a problem.
I want to fix this but i don't know how.
Any help would be much appreciated.
UPDATE:
I think i've found the right file to edit.
It's called "wc-booking-functions" inside "includes" folder of "woocommerce-bookings" which says this:

```js
/**
 * Give this function a booking or resource ID, and a range of dates and get back
 * how many places are available for the requested quantity of bookings for all blocks within those dates.
 *
 * Replaces the WC_Product_Booking::get_available_bookings method.
 *
 * @param  WC_Product_Booking | integer $bookable_product Can be a product object or a booking prouct ID.
 * @param  integer $start_date
 * @param  integer $end_date
 * @param  integer|null optional $resource_id
 * @param  integer $qty
 * @param  array   $intervals
 * @return array|int|boolean|WP_Error False if no places/blocks are available or the dates are invalid.
 */
function wc_bookings_get_total_available_bookings_for_range( $bookable_product, $start_date, $end_date, $resource_id = null, $qty = 1, $intervals = array() ) {
    // alter the end date to limit it to go up to one slot if the setting is enabled
    if ( $bookable_product->get_check_start_block_only() ) {
        $end_date = strtotime( '+ ' . $bookable_product->get_duration() . ' ' . $bookable_product->get_duration_unit(), $start_date );
    }
    // Check the date is not in the past
    if ( date( 'Ymd', $start_date ) < date( 'Ymd', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Check we have a resource if needed
    $booking_resource = $resource_id ? $bookable_product->get_resource( $resource_id ) : null;
    if ( $bookable_product->has_resources() && ! is_numeric( $resource_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $min_date   = $bookable_product->get_min_date();
    $max_date   = $bookable_product->get_max_date();
    $check_from = strtotime( "midnight +{$min_date['value']} {$min_date['unit']}", current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
    $check_to   = strtotime( "+{$max_date['value']} {$max_date['unit']}", current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
    // Min max checks
    if ( 'month' === $bookable_product->get_duration_unit() ) {
        $check_to = strtotime( 'midnight', strtotime( date( 'Y-m-t', $check_to ) ) );
    }
    if ( $end_date < $check_from || $start_date > $check_to ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Get availability of each resource - no resource has been chosen yet
    if ( $bookable_product->has_resources() && ! $resource_id ) {
        return $bookable_product->get_all_resources_availability( $start_date, $end_date, $qty );
    } else {
        // If we are checking for bookings for a specific resource, or have none.
        $check_date     = $start_date;
        if ( in_array( $bookable_product->get_duration_unit(), array( 'minute', 'hour' ) ) ) {
            if ( ! $bookable_product->check_availability_rules_against_time( $start_date, $end_date, $resource_id ) ) {
             return false;
            }
        } else {
            while ( $check_date < $end_date ) {
                if ( ! $bookable_product->check_availability_rules_against_date( $check_date, $resource_id ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
                if ( $bookable_product->get_check_start_block_only() ) {
                    break; // Only need to check first day
                }
                $check_date = strtotime( '+1 day', $check_date );
            }
        }
        // Get blocks availability
        return $bookable_product->get_blocks_availability( $start_date, $end_date, $qty, $booking_resource, $intervals );
    }
}

/**
 * Find available and booked blocks for specific resources (if any) and return them as array.
 *
 * @param \WC_Product_Booking $bookable_product
 * @param  array  $blocks
 * @param  array  $intervals
 * @param  integer $resource_id
 * @param  integer $from The starting date for the set of blocks
 * @param  integer $to
 * @return array
 *
 * @version  1.10.5
 */
function wc_bookings_get_time_slots( $bookable_product, $blocks, $intervals = array(), $resource_id = 0, $from = 0, $to = 0, $include_sold_out = false ) {
    $transient_name               = 'book_ts_' . md5( http_build_query( array( $bookable_product->get_id(), $resource_id, $from, $to, $include_sold_out ) ) );
    $available_slots              = WC_Bookings_Cache::get( $transient_name );
    $booking_slots_transient_keys = array_filter( (array) WC_Bookings_Cache::get( 'booking_slots_transient_keys' ) );

    if ( ! isset( $booking_slots_transient_keys[ $bookable_product->get_id() ] ) ) {
        $booking_slots_transient_keys[ $bookable_product->get_id() ] = array();
    }

    if ( ! in_array( $transient_name, $booking_slots_transient_keys[ $bookable_product->get_id() ] ) ) {
        $booking_slots_transient_keys[ $bookable_product->get_id() ][] = $transient_name;
        // Give array of keys a long ttl because if it expires we won't be able to flush the keys when needed.
        // We can't use 0 to never expire because then WordPress will autoload the option on every page.
        WC_Bookings_Cache::set( 'booking_slots_transient_keys', $booking_slots_transient_keys, YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    if ( false === $available_slots ) {
        if ( empty( $intervals ) ) {
            $default_interval = 'hour' === $bookable_product->get_duration_unit() ? $bookable_product->get_duration() * 60 : $bookable_product->get_duration();
            $interval         = $bookable_product->get_min_duration() * $default_interval;
            $intervals        = array( $interval, $default_interval );
        }

        list( $interval, $base_interval ) = $intervals;
        $interval = $bookable_product->get_check_start_block_only() ? $base_interval : $interval;

        if ( ! $include_sold_out ) {
            $blocks   = $bookable_product->get_available_blocks( array(
                'blocks'      => $blocks,
                'intervals'   => $intervals,
                'resource_id' => $resource_id,
                'from'        => $from,
                'to'          => $to,
            ) );
        }

        $booking_resource = $resource_id ? $bookable_product->get_resource( $resource_id ) : null;
        $available_slots  = array();
        $has_qty          = ! is_null( $booking_resource ) ? $booking_resource->has_qty() : false;
        $has_resources    = $bookable_product->has_resources();

        /*
         * The calculations below are performed using array of minutes for the following reason:
         *
         * We are trying to figure-out resource and availability quote for the booking $block.
         * In order to do that we have to check all other bookings that are already booked and
         * take time overlapping the $block. Inconveniently bookings in $existing_bookings may come
         * from products that are different than our $bookable_product. This means that their start
         * and end times may not be aligned with our product $block and $interval. We can't because of that
         * check quote and resources 1 to 1 but we need to look at individual minutes.
         */
        $existing_bookings = WC_Booking_Data_Store::get_all_existing_bookings( $bookable_product, $from, $to );

        foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
            $resources = array();

            // Figure out how much qty have, either based on combined resource quantity,
            // single resource, or just product.
            if ( $has_resources && ( ! is_a( $booking_resource, 'WC_Product_Booking_Resource' ) || ! $has_qty ) ) {
                $available_qty = 0;

                foreach ( $bookable_product->get_resources() as $resource ) {

                    // Only include if it is available for this selection.
                    if ( ! WC_Product_Booking_Rule_Manager::check_availability_rules_against_date( $bookable_product, $resource->get_id(), $block ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ( in_array( $bookable_product->get_duration_unit(), array( 'minute', 'hour' ) )
                        && ! $bookable_product->check_availability_rules_against_time( $block, strtotime( "+{$interval} minutes", $block ), $resource->get_id() ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $qty = $resource->get_qty();
                    $available_qty += $qty;
                    $resources[ $resource->get_id() ] = $qty;
                }
            } elseif ( $has_resources && $has_qty ) {
                // Only include if it is available for this selection. We set this block to be bookable by default, unless some of the rules apply.
                if ( ! $bookable_product->check_availability_rules_against_time( $block, strtotime( "+{$interval} minutes", $block ), $booking_resource->get_id() ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                $qty = $booking_resource->get_qty();
                $available_qty = $qty;
                $resources[ $booking_resource->get_id() ] = $qty;
            } else {
                $available_qty = $bookable_product->get_qty();
                $resources[0] = $bookable_product->get_qty();
            }

            $qty_booked_in_block = 0;

            $inteval_in_minutes = in_array( $bookable_product->get_duration_unit(), array( 'minute', 'hour' ) ) ? $interval : $interval * ( DAY_IN_SECONDS / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );

            // Prepare ( array ) of minutes we are looking at.
            $block_minutes_array = wc_bookings_get_block_minutes_array( $block, $inteval_in_minutes );

            // Spread resources and booked quote using minutes array.
            $resources = array_map(
                function( $r ) use ( $block_minutes_array ) {
                    return array_fill_keys( array_keys( $block_minutes_array ), $r );
                },
                $resources
            );
            $qty_booked_in_block = $block_minutes_array;

            if ( ! empty( $existing_bookings ) ) {
                foreach ( $existing_bookings as $existing_booking ) {
                    if ( $existing_booking->is_within_block( $block, strtotime( "+{$inteval_in_minutes} minutes", $block ) ) ) {
                        $existing_booking_product    = $existing_booking->get_product();
                        $qty_to_add                  = $existing_booking_product->has_person_qty_multiplier() ? max( 1, array_sum( $existing_booking->get_persons() ) ) : 1;
                        // Default resource in case we don't have anything in product or existing bookings.
                        $res                         = 0;
                        if ( $has_resources ) {
                            if ( $existing_booking->get_resource_id() === absint( $resource_id ) ) {
                                // Include the quantity to subtract if an existing booking matches the selected resource id
                                $res = $resource_id;
                            } elseif ( ( is_null( $booking_resource ) || ! $has_qty ) && $existing_booking->get_resource() ) {
                                // Include the quantity to subtract if the resource is auto selected (null/resource id empty)
                                // but the existing booking includes a resource
                                $res = $existing_booking->get_resource_id();
                            } else {
                                // We have resource but the existing booking resource does not overlap so we don't need to take it into consideration.
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        $existing_booking_block      = $existing_booking->get_start_cached();
                        $existing_booking_interval   = ceil( ( $existing_booking->get_end_cached() - $existing_booking_block ) / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
                        $booking_block_minutes_array = wc_bookings_get_block_minutes_array( $existing_booking_block, $existing_booking_interval );
                        $qty_booked_in_block         = wc_bookings_add_at_intersection( $qty_booked_in_block, $booking_block_minutes_array, $qty_to_add );
                        $res                         = $has_resources ? $existing_booking->get_resource_id() : 0;
                        $resources[ $res ]           = ( isset( $resources[ $res ] ) ? $resources[ $res ] : $block_minutes_array );
                        $resources[ $res ]           = wc_bookings_add_at_intersection( $resources[ $res ], $booking_block_minutes_array, - $qty_to_add );
                    }
                }
            }

            // The minute with minimal resource value is the actual resource available from the perspective of the whole $block.
            $resources = array_map(
                function( $r ) {
                    return min( $r );
                },
                $resources
            );
            // The minute with maximal booked quota value is the actual booked quota from the perspective of the whole $block.
            $qty_booked_in_block = max( $qty_booked_in_block );

            $available_slots[ $block ] = array(
                'booked'    => $qty_booked_in_block,
                'available' => $available_qty - $qty_booked_in_block,
                'resources' => $resources,
            );
        }

        WC_Bookings_Cache::set( $transient_name, $available_slots );
    }

    return $available_slots;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is going to be super hard to help with since you are asking about a specific issue, for a specific plugin on your site that you probably can't replicate here. Also, **NEVER** edit a plugin's files. If you update that plugin, any customization will be lost. I would reach out to the plugin developer for help.

Comment: Thank you for the concern, but, I think, it's a pretty common problem for the buyers of this plugin given it's one of the few solutions for this business and the setup made by the creators is pretty dumb. Moreover, obviously, I backup everything regularly, as every website owner should, so, once found a solution for this problem, I'll solve this problem again easily 'till the creators will (hopefully) address this situation. Thank you anyway!